# alter width dynamically in paperjs

Tags: paperjs

I'm trying to alter the width of a rectangle using event.count. 
However I'm failing to find my variable "thewidth" from the onFrame function.

i've tried this.path.thewidth / thewidth / myLine.thewidth..... all give the error  "thewidth is not defined".

(i'm new to this, and am struggling with what must be basic tasks)

Any pointers gratefully received.

```
var growLine = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize: function() {
this.initialPosition = new paper.Point(20,60);
var thewidth = 2;
var theheight =2;
this.path = new paper.Path.Rectangle(new paper.Point(748, 270), thewidth, theheight);


this.path.strokeColor = 'green';
this.animationStartFrame = null;
this.path.model = this;
this.activated = false;
},

trigger: function() {
this.activated = !this.activated;
if(this.activated)
    this.path.fillColor = 'red';
    toggleOnFrameListener(this, this.onFrame.bind(this.path));
    },

onFrame: function(event) {
if(this.animationStartFrame == null)
      this.animationStartFrame = event.count;
var animationFrame = event.count - this.animationStartFrame;

console.log(thewidth);
}
});
```

Comment: how can I make a rectangle grow wider using onFrame ?

Answer (score 0):

thewidth is defined within a function and is local to that function. You will need to declare this.thewidth, make it global, or provide another way to access the value in order to reference it outside the scope of the function it is declared in.